# How do you export Shape Keys?

Tags: mesh, export, shape-keys

I want to export the mesh made with shape keys as obj files. My attempts have resulted in exporting only the basis mesh. How can I export the deformed mesh?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5364/how-to-apply-shape-keys

Comment: Set the shapekey value to 1.0 before exporting. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86678/935) has a script to export them all.

Answer (score 4):

When exporting shape keys for Poser morph targets in obj format I found the following to work:

• Export from Object view with key value = 1.

• Set export options to "Polygroups", "Keep vertex order" and "Apply Modifiers"

Note that the Poser import scale option must be set at 100% with all other options off.

Comment: What about exporting to .fbx?